How to Configure Event Hub to Consume Storage Account with Private Endpoint
I am trying to connect my Event Hub instance to Storage Account using a private endpoint. I can successfully do this when my storage account is public but when I attempt to connect to the storage account when its private, I get the error

Error connecting to Blob storage "Access Forbidden: Invalid
credentials provided for Blob storage account" Error Code:
AuthorizationFailure

My question is, how do you consume a storage account with no public access from event hubs?


How your connecting through code or portal? if code please provide code?

refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/vnet-endpoint-storage-event-hub?tabs=storage-account @DrSchizo


Configure Event Hub to Consume Storage Account with Private Endpoint

Directly disabling the access on storage account restricting all inbound traffic to SA. Which in result it was not in a place to allow any messages.
As per Microsoftdoc We need to allow the trusted services in the storage account where eventhub in this case as trusted device it will allow only one resource type.

This will move your access permission setting to selected IP and vnet however this only able to access the input from the selected services.


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#setting-up-event-hubs-capture
Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks | Microsoft Learn
Quickstart: Send or receive events using .NET - Azure Event Hubs | Microsoft Learn
